# How do I configure PATH variables so I can run packages on the CLI?

Tags: bash, path, command-line-interface

I have Python 3.7 installed on my Mac and installed the package `pipreqs` with the command `pip3 install pipreqs --user`.

When I try to run `pipreqs path/to/file` I get an `-bash: pipreqs: command not found` error.

I get that it's looking in the wrong place, which is why the package can't be found.

I've been seeing a few posts like [this](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/69) helping people reset their paths. I really have no idea where to start. Is this something I can just do from the command line, or do I actually have to edit a file using vim or something. Do I `~/.bashrc` directly?

When I run run `echo $path` I get

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/dev/opt/bin:/Users/dev/opt/bin:/Users/dev/dev/bin:/Users/dev/.local/bin` My username is `dev`.

EDIT:

```
$ pip3 show -f pipreqs | grep /pipreqs
Home-page: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs
  ../../../bin/pipreqs
  pipreqs/__pycache__/pipreqs.cpython-37.pyc
  pipreqs/pipreqs.py
```

Comment: What does `which pipreqs` return?

Comment: @Sonny `which pipreqs` returns nothing

Comment: `../../../bin/pipreqs` is a relative path, use `pip show -f pipreqs | grep Location:` to have the starting point as absolute path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was the fix:

```
$ open ~/.bash_profile
```

Then, in the editor,

```
export PATH="/Users/<my-username>/Library/Python/<python-edition>/bin:$PATH"
```

Then save the editor (with `ctrl-s`).

Then you need to 'activate' the `.bash_profile` using `source`. I believe you can also just close and reopen terminal.

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

`pipreqs` now works as a command.

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me on Debian 10 was adding the line below to `.profile`:

```
alias pipreqs='python3 -m pipreqs.pipreqs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
$ pip show -f pipreqs | grep /pipreqs
```

to know the location of your installed files, then you can either run the executables or add their path to `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Added the output to the question. How did I add to PATH?

Comment: `export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/dir/where/pipreqsExists` To make it permanent , add to `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: exactly, add the **absolute** path not the relative one given by `pip`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on Windows, run these in Administrator PowerShell. Make sure to replace the path mentioned in line two with the path to your Python installation + `\Scripts\`.

```
$oldpath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).path
$newpath = "$oldpath;C:\path\to\Python\python38\Scripts\"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $newPath
```

Here it takes the old global windows path in the 1st line then appends `C:\path\to\Python\python38\Scripts\` to it in the second. Then saves the path in the 3rd line.

Comment: This did not work for me; I continued to get the same error even after running as Admin